# imshow plotting very large integers, but "dtype object cannot be converted to float"

Tags: python, matplotlib, precision, axis-labels, floating-accuracy

I have the following code, plotting a function on a grid, where the function happens to have a very large integer value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FuncFormatter
import numpy as np # thanks to user @simon pointing out I had forgotten this

p = 13
counts = [[0 for x in range(p)] for y in range(p)]
counts[0][0] = 1000000000
unique_counts = np.unique(counts)
plt.imshow(counts, cmap='viridis', origin='lower', extent=[0, p-1, 0, p-1])
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=unique_counts, format=ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: format(int(x), ',')))  # Format tick labels with commas
plt.show()
```

Running this in GoogleColab, it runs perfectly fine and gives the nice plot
[image]

However, if I bump up `counts[0][0] = 1000000000000000000000` say, then I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-0ec4c2551685> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 counts[0][0] = 100000000000000000000
      7 unique_counts = np.unique(counts)
----> 8 plt.imshow(counts, cmap='viridis', origin='lower', extent=[0, p-1, 0, p-1])
      9 cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=unique_counts, format=ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
     10 cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: format(int(x), ',')))  # Format tick labels with commas

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    699         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and
    700                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
--> 701             raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
    702                             "float".format(self._A.dtype))
    703 

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

I would like very much to be able to plot functions that take very large integer values with exact precision (so rounding/using floats would not be good). Is this possible?

EDIT: someone was understandably confused by this seemingly useless level of precision in a plot; I clarified that what's actually important for me is actually being able to read the exact value off the **colorbar labels** (for number theory applications, I need an exact count for the number of points on some varieties mod p). So I'm ok with the plot being slightly off, but I do really want the **colorbar labels** to be exact.

Comment: Your use case isn't very clear.  When converted to a plot, the large precision will necessarily be converted to pixels on a screen (or on a paper), you won't be able to see a color nuance or a pixel position of 1 in 10,000.  Floats in numpy are 64 bits, or a precision of about 15 decimal digits.  Integers in numpy format, when compiled for a 64 bit machine, have 18 exact digits.  Anyway, for plotting these are internally converted to floats.

Comment: @JohanC fair enough. What's actually important for me is actually being able to read the exact value off the colorbar labels (for number theory applications, I need an exact count for the number of points on some varieties mod p). So I'm ok with the plot being slightly off, but I do really want the colorbar labels to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New answer

*(For my original answer, see the section below.)*

Based on the question's update, from which it became clear that the essential information that should be retained is the precise integer values on the *colorbar tick labels*, here is my updated answer. Its crucial idea is:

- For the colorbar tick *positions* and image data, use floating point values (as these are the only ones that Matplotlib can internally deal with; see original answer below).
- For the colorbar tick *labels*, use the given integer values: provide them to Matplotlib as a list of already formatted strings (following [this approach)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html).

Here is the corresponding code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import numpy as np

p = 13
counts = [[0 for x in range(p)] for y in range(p)]
# Provide some huge ints for demonstration purposes
counts[ 0][ 0] = 100000000000000000008
counts[ 0][-1] = counts[ 0][ 0] // 2
counts[-1][ 0] = counts[ 0][-1] // 2
counts[-1][-1] = counts[-1][ 0] // 2
# Get the unique values (without Numpy, just to be sure)
unique_counts = sorted(set(val for row in counts for val in row))
# Provide the image and tick *positions* as float values to avoid casting error
counts_img = np.array(counts, dtype=float)
counts_ticks = [float(val) for val in unique_counts]
# Provide the tick *labels* as strings generated from the original integer vals
counts_ticks_labels = [f'{val:,}' for val in unique_counts]
# Display everything
plt.imshow(counts_img, cmap='viridis', origin='lower', extent=[0, p-1, 0, p-1])
cbar = plt.colorbar(format=ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
cbar.set_ticks(ticks=counts_ticks, labels=counts_ticks_labels)
plt.show()
```

In older versions of Matplotlib, you might need to adjust the last three lines as follows:

```py
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=counts_ticks, format=ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(counts_ticks_labels)
plt.show()
```

And here is the resulting plot:
[image: plot resulting from provided code]

### Original answer

#### Short answer

I currently do not see a way to *exactly* pass huge integers to `imshow()`, due to the inner workings of Matplotlib relying on Numpy arrays for holding the image data. If you can live with approximate values, use

```py
counts[0][0] = float(100000000000000000000)
```

#### Long answer

The reason for the error that you see is that your nested list of image data is internally converted to a Numpy array by Matplotlib before displaying it. In Matplotlib's current version, this happens in [`cbook.safe_masked_invalid()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2a840e4ef25795e092f28c4b6dc0aed9a015083b/lib/matplotlib/cbook.py#L733), which is called by [`‎_ImageBase._normalize_image_array()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2a840e4ef25795e092f28c4b6dc0aed9a015083b/lib/matplotlib/image.py#L686), which is called by [`_ImageBase.set_data()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2a840e4ef25795e092f28c4b6dc0aed9a015083b/lib/matplotlib/image.py#L725), which is called by [`Axes.imshow()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5770).

The chain of problems here is the following:

1. Huge integers (i.e. integers that cannot be represented by Numpy's [`int_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_) data type, I assume) are converted to Numpy's `object` data type by default. This happens for your data with `counts[0][0] = 100000000000000000000`, but not with `counts[0][0] = 1000000000`. You can easily check the corresponding Numpy behavior as follows:

   ```py
   str(np.array([100000000000000000000]).dtype)
   # >>> 'object'
   str(np.array([1000000000]).dtype)
   # >>> 'int64'
   ```

   In Matplotlib, as already mentioned, this happens in [`cbook.safe_masked_invalid()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2a840e4ef25795e092f28c4b6dc0aed9a015083b/lib/matplotlib/cbook.py#L733); more precisely, it happens in the line `x = np.array(x, subok=True, copy=copy)`, where `x` refers to your nested list `counts`.
2. After that, [`_ImageBase._normalize_image_array()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2a840e4ef25795e092f28c4b6dc0aed9a015083b/lib/matplotlib/image.py#L687) checks whether the resulting array's data type is either `uint8` or whether it can be cast to the `float` data type. Neither is true for Numpy's `object` data type, so the error is raised.

To avoid this chain of problems, the only possibility that I see is converting your data to float values or to a float array yourself, once the values become too big, before passing them to `imshow()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis! I responded to a comment above, saying that what's actually important for me is actually being able to read the exact value off the colorbar labels (for number theory applications, I need an exact count for the number of points on some varieties mod p). So I'm ok with the plot being slightly off, but I do really want the colorbar labels to be exact. Would it be possible to pass these huge integer values to the colorbar ticks, if not imshow?

Comment: @D.R Thank your for your clarification. I will see what I can do once I find the time. I am pretty much optimistic though: there are ways to produce colorbars independent of the image content, and such an approach could be a last resort if others fail.

Comment: @D.R See my updated answer (section "New answer" above). I did not need to customize the whole colorbar, I just had to provide custom labels for the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Float has problems dealing with large integers. The following code worked for me, I hope this is the result that you want.
It is always a bit better to have readable numbers in scientific notations than having extremely large numbers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import numpy as np

p = 13
counts = [[0 for x in range(p)] for y in range(p)]
counts[0][0] = 100000000000000000000000

# Convert counts to a NumPy array
counts_array = np.array(counts, dtype=float)

# Create the plot
plt.imshow(counts_array, cmap='viridis', origin='lower', extent=[0, p-1, 0, p-1])
cbar = plt.colorbar()

cbar.set_ticks([np.min(counts_array), np.max(counts_array)])
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False, useMathText=True))
cbar.update_ticks()

plt.show()
```

In the above code, even though imshow and the plot worked, the large numbers were still not shown in the colorbar. I have added here a new snippet, that would help print the numbers. I couldn't make matplotlib to print the numbers, so now I format the colorbar explicitly using strings.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

p = 13
counts = [[0 for x in range(p)] for y in range(p)]
counts[0][0] = 1000000000000000000000

# Convert counts to a NumPy array
counts_array = np.array(counts, dtype=float)

# Create the plot
plt.imshow(counts_array, cmap='viridis', origin='lower', extent=[0, p-1, 0, p-1])
cbar = plt.colorbar()

# Set custom tick labels for the colorbar
tick_labels = [f'{int(x):,}' for x in cbar.get_ticks()]
cbar.set_ticklabels(tick_labels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I responded to a comment above, saying that what's actually important for me is actually being able to read the exact value off the colorbar labels (for number theory applications, I need an exact count for the number of points on some varieties mod p). So I'm ok with the plot being slightly off, but I do really want the colorbar labels to be exact. Would it be possible to pass these huge integer values to the colorbar ticks, if not imshow?

Comment: I have edited the answer and have included a way to also display large number in the colorbar. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JD2911 I don't think this exactly produces what D.R expects. See, for example, what happens if `counts[0][0] = 1000000000000000000001`. If I understand D.R's comment correctly, this should produce a tick label with this exact value (i.e. 1000000000000000000001), which currently does not happen in the provided answer.